# Cessna 140 1946 TT

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Hello I’m first time buyer airplane, I’m buying Cessna 140 1946 and it has TT 12.400
TSMOH  400  , needs anual  and ADSB
I’m I getting in trouble here ? Is too many hrs ? $17,000

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you are asking if you should buy the airplane we can't help you, as that is asking for opinions rather than fact based answers. If you have a specific question then I suggest you edit and ask it instead.

Answer (score 2):

If this airplane has not been actively flown recently (and the lack of an annual and ADSB indicates not) then I would be cautious.  Has nothing to do w/being an old C-140 and everything to do w/neglected hangar queens.

Another question is will a C-140 bring you joy?  Have flown a two seat tail dragger?  They are more like kites, and a hot or windy day will be a challenge.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The hours aren't really a problem.  Sitting around unused outside is the killer. These airplanes get ruined by corrosion long before they get worn out.  Of course you're going to have the airplane inspected by somebody who knows 140s as a condition of purchase right?

They are bulletproof generally, but there are a couple of areas to watch for, like cracks in the front door post wing attach etc (I believe there is an AD). You have to make sure the airplane is compliant with ADs.  And the engine is a big question mark. You can spend a fortune on the engine if you don't do your due diligence.

Did I mention that you should be having someone expert in 140s go over it for you right?  If you aren't and are just buying it as is, well get ready for possibly 10 or 20k of expenses if the engine is toast or the plane has corrosion.  Times and logs mean little.  What really counts is expert eyes going over it carefully.

If it checks out, 17k is an amazing deal for a solid nice flying 140.  They are delightful airplanes.